# how to call Cucumber stepDefinitions from another project from the same level?

Tags: node.js, typescript, cucumber, devops, cucumberjs

I have a project integration_test that contains all test projects.
I am using the cucumberjs/typescript/nodejs.

In Project1 is implemented the login and I want just to call in Scenarios from Project2 and Project3. The login step use the login implementation from Project1.

**How should be the script from package.json from Project2, in case the login step implementation is in Project1?**

current script in package.json Project2:

```
"test:project2": cucumber-js ./tests/ --require '.tests/**/*.ts' --exit"
```

See below the folder structures:

```
   integration_test
          Project1
             -tests
               -features
               -step_definitions
             -package.json
             -cucumber.js
          Project2
            -tests
               -features
               -step_definitions
             -package.json
             -cucumber.js
          Project3
             -tests
               -features
               -step_definitions
             -package.json
             -cucumber.js
```

cucumber.js contains:

```
let common = [
  'features/**/*.feature', // Specify our feature files
  '--require-module ts-node/register', // Load TypeScript module
  '--format node_modules/cucumber-pretty' // Load custom formatter
].join(' ');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use cucumberjs 'require' option to make this use case success. Just define your cucumber.js file with this content:

```
let common = [
  './**/tests/features/', // Specify our feature files
    '--require ./../**/tests/step_definitions/**/', // Load step definitions
    '--require ./support/', // Load hooks
].join(' ');
```

By this way, cucumberjs loads all step definitions defined in all projects listed..